# Using create-react-app's npm startwith AWS Cloud9

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, create-react-app, npm-start, aws-cloud9

I am attempting to use `create-react-app` in AWS Cloud9. While I have no problems creating the app, when I try to run `npm start` I just get [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ1GZ.png). When I clicked on "Why am I seeing this?" I was taken to [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-app-preview-http), which led me to turn on HTTPS. While HTTPS was enabled, it did not fix the issue. `create-react-app`'s Github page suggested that `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` is required for virtual machines, but that also did not fix the issue: it now creates a blank page, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNKmP.png). Finally, thinking that perhaps the issue was due to some accidental change, I deleted the directory and made a fresh one, but the issue persisted.

Any insight on how this can be resolved would be appreciated.

Comment: You did run npm install first, right?

Comment: @TGarrett Yes. I also ran it again, just to be sure--still no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue. For me I was just going about it the wrong way and I can preview my application by going to Preview at the top of the IDE and then Preview Running Application.

Comment: Thanks a ton for that answer! I spent hours figuring out how to show the running app using the built in browser in aws cloud9.